# ¿Cuál me recomiendan usar laravel 5.1 o laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero desarrollar un proyecto con Laravel, y debería elegir entre Laravel 5.1 y 5.3.

Me gustaría tomar una decisión informada, pero la [lista de mejoras en la versión 5.3](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3) no me sirve para determinar qué debería elegir.

¿Qué aspectos debería tener en cuenta para mi aplicación?

- ¿Si utilizo la versión 5.1 en mis primeras aplicaciones, me estaría perdiendo de algo realmente importante?
- ¿Si utilizo la versión 5.3, tendría problemas de compatibilidad con otro sistemas o soluciones que me dificulten la implementación?
- ¿Los cambios son realmente significativos como para que los ejemplos en la web/documentación que ya pueda existir para 5.1 no aplique en Laravel 5.3?
- ¿Existe algún otro punto relevante que debería tener en cuenta?

Comment: Siempre es mejor migrar a una versión superior. Debes revisar la documentación de la nueva versión y analizar cuál es el impacto sobre tu aplicativo. Dependiendo de qué tan complejo sea tu proyecto o no. La decisión es personal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En los proyectos generalmente se usa el LTS para cuando necesitas que en producción tenga bastante soporte, siempre depende de tus necesidades, en este caso si necesitas compatibilidad especial usa la versión 5.1, en caso contrario yo optaría por la más reciente puesto que puede traer las nuevas características que llegaran a ser importantes en el futuro.

Acá te dejo un enlace con una discusión similar:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/start-a-new-project-should-i-start-with-51-or-52

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Si utilizo la versión 5.1 en mis primeras aplicaciones, me estaría
>   perdiendo de algo realmente importante?

Dependerá si las nuevas funcionalidades implementadas tienen sentido para ti, hay varias cosas que te "perderías" pero nada que no puedas hacer tu o que no te permitan hacer una aplicacion como la desees.

> ¿Si utilizo la versión 5.3, tendría problemas de compatibilidad con
>   otro sistemas o soluciones que me dificulten la implementación?

No necesariamente, mientras tengas los requisitos mínimos que pide la 5.3, no tendrías que tener problemas de compatibilidad.

> ¿Los cambios son realmente significativos como para que los ejemplos
>   en la web/documentación que ya pueda existir para 5.1 no aplique en
>   Laravel 5.3?

Por supuesto que pueden haber incompatibilidades, si estás trabajando con la 5.1 lee la documentación de la 5.1, no veas otra.

> ¿Existe algún otro punto relevante que debería tener en cuenta?

Las version 5.1 es LTS (Long Term Support), el soporte de largo plazo significa que se seguirán desarrollando fixes y problemas de seguridad durante 5 años. Este Julio 2017 terminaría el LTS y es muy probable que la versión 5.5 sea la próxima LTS.

En teoría entonces, la versión 5.1 **sería la más estable** de todas las 5.X y podría ser la mejor elección si tu aplicación debe privilegiar la seguridad y estabilidad frente a nuevas funcionalidades y posibles bugs que aún no se hayan encontrado por tener una versión tan reciente.